# Rails 5.2.1 Active Admin ActionView::Template::Error when upgraded rails from version 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activeadmin, actionview

I have updated rails version from 4.2.6 to rails 5.2.1.

When tried to access admin/login url is is giving error as

> ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0..1)):
>       1: insert_tag active_admin_application.view_factory["page"]

**I have not overridden any part of activeadmin views in application.**

Not used pagination related gem also.

I am using below versions

```
ruby 2.3.4
gem 'rails', '5.2.1'
gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.3.0'
gem 'rails_friendly_urls', '~> 1.0.0'
```

Full trace of the error log is

```
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0..1)):
    1: insert_tag active_admin_application.view_factory["page"]

rails_friendly_urls (1.0.1) lib/rails_friendly_urls/route_sets/rails3.rb:5:in `url_for'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:273:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:214:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:331:in `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/resource/routes.rb:54:in `public_send'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/resource/routes.rb:54:in `collection_path'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/resource/routes.rb:8:in `route_collection_path'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/resource/menu.rb:30:in `block in default_menu_options'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/view_helpers/method_or_proc_helper.rb:90:in `instance_exec'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/view_helpers/method_or_proc_helper.rb:90:in `render_in_context'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/menu_item.rb:71:in `url'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/menu_item.rb:92:in `real_url?'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/menu_item.rb:78:in `display?'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/menu.rb:74:in `block in items'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/menu.rb:74:in `select'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/menu.rb:74:in `items'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/views/tabbed_navigation.rb:27:in `menu_items'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/views/tabbed_navigation.rb:37:in `build_menu'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/views/tabbed_navigation.rb:22:in `build'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:30:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/views/header.rb:22:in `build_global_navigation'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/views/header.rb:13:in `build'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:30:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:67:in `build_header'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in build_page'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:50:in `block in build_page'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:49:in `build_page'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:10:in `build'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:30:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
activeadmin (1.3.1) app/views/active_admin/page/index.html.arb:2:in `block in __usr_local_rvm_gems_ruby_______gems_activeadmin_______app_views_active_admin_page_index_html_arb__684239489_129398360'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:45:in `instance_eval'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:45:in `initialize'
activeadmin (1.3.1) app/views/active_admin/page/index.html.arb:1:in `new'
activeadmin (1.3.1) app/views/active_admin/page/index.html.arb:1:in `__usr_local_rvm_gems_ruby_______gems_activeadmin_______app_views_active_admin_page_index_html_arb__684239489_129398360'
actionview (5.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:159:in `block in render'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
actionview (5.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:354:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (5.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `render'
actionview (5.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (5.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:44:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionview (5.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:43:in `instrument'
actionview (5.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (5.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (5.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (5.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:16:in `render'
actionview (5.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:44:in `render_template'
actionview (5.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:25:in `render'
actionview (5.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionview (5.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:84:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:142:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `block in ms'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `ms'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:46:in `block in render'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (5.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:31:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:45:in `render'
meta-tags (2.10.0) lib/meta_tags/controller_helper.rb:20:in `render'
activeadmin (1.3.1) lib/active_admin/page_controller.rb:14:in `index'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:194:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:109:in `block in run_callbacks'
audited (4.8.0) lib/audited/sweeper.rb:14:in `around'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
audited (4.8.0) lib/audited/sweeper.rb:14:in `around'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:136:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'
actionview (5.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:32:in `process'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in `call'
activerecord (5.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:86:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'
```

Can anybody tell me, where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`rails_friendly_urls` has [not been updated since 2015](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails_friendly_urls), I'm pretty sure it is obsolete and you will have to remove or replace it to upgrade to Rails 5, the issue is not with ActiveAdmin.

Comment: Thanks @Piers C, yes, rails_friendly_urls is not supported for the rails 5, no code is written as per [https://github.com/calonso/rails_friendly_urls/blob/master/lib/rails_friendly_urls.rb]

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this,

Error was due to rails_friendly_urls gems.

In rails_friendly_urls gem https://github.com/calonso/rails_friendly_urls/blob/master/lib/rails_friendly_urls.rb

```
case RailsFriendlyUrls.rails_version
when '4.2'
  require 'rails_friendly_urls/urls/rails4_2'
when '4.0', '4.1'
  require 'rails_friendly_urls/urls/rails4_0'
when '3.2'
  require 'rails_friendly_urls/route_sets/rails3'
else
  raise NotImplementedError.new "Rails Friendly URLs gem doesn't support Rails #{Rails.version}"
end
```

Above part is written & it is not updated since 2015.

So we can have gem locally and change above file as

```
case RailsFriendlyUrls.rails_version
when '4.2', '5.2'
  require 'rails_friendly_urls/route_sets/rails4_2'
  require 'rails_friendly_urls/urls/rails4_2'
else
  raise NotImplementedError.new "Rails Friendly URLs gem doesn't support Rails #{Rails.version}"
end
```

This will support in rails 5.2.1